# XPM: Update Preview not working for Binary files in SDL Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: experience-manager, updatepreview

Everything works fine, but binary fields are not rendering when I click on the update preview button in XPM. Content on the Page is fine and updated also after editing.

I am getting a `DirectoryNotFoundException` exception in log files for all binary files on the Page.

> Error Handling www.test.com/languagename/imagefolder/imagename_tcm444-555555.png
>               ...                                   System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException (mscorlib)
>               ...                                   Could not find a part of the path 'F:\WWW\publishedcontentfolder\country\images\country\images\imagename_tcm444-555555_6e489499-f95a-4685-ae26-1cf9f44731ab.png'.
>               ...                                      at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)

It is writing the **country\image** twice while requesting binary for update preview button click.

Comment: Have you set a maximum size for binary items for preview in the XPM session preview settings, and are the binaries you are requesting larger than that?

Comment: In the path I see: publiahedcontentfodler, is it correct? I guess, it should be publishedcontentfolder (two problems: a instead of s and ld swapped)

Comment: @ Bart : I will check for the binary size and will let you know the result.
@Hiren : That was typo and not the actual path .

Comment: What are the path and URL settings and images path and URL settings in the publication properties?